# TCL string map for ( to \(

Tags: string, replace, tcl

how to do this

```
puts [string map { ( ) "\(" "\)"} (3.8.001)]
```

o\p I'm getting $tclsh main.tcl

```
(3.8.001)
```

I'm expecting

```
\(3.8.001\)
```

help me to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I'm confused about how exactly to write a complex `string map` with backslashes involved, I try building the mapping list with `list`. I might then use the literal it produces rather than having my script contain the actual `list` command call, but that's purely optimisation on my part. (And a very low value one; the bytecode compiler does it for me if all the arguments to `list` are literals.) In particularly tricky cases, I'll build it by stages with `lappend`, but that's only where what is going on is a true head-scratcher!

Also, the mapping is supposed to be “`replaceA withA replaceB withB ...`”; you were putting `)` and `"\("` in the wrong order, and the result would not have been expected to work at all.

```
set mapping [list "(" "\\(" ")" "\\)"]
# puts "mapping is “$mapping”";  # Yay for unicode quote characters!
puts [string map $mapping (3.8.001)]
```

---

The sequence you were looking for is this, with a few more braces and fewer double-quotes, but I encourage you to learn how to work this out for yourself…

```
puts [string map {( {\(} ) {\)}} "(3.8.001)"]
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use the `string map` as follows,

```
puts [string map { ( "\\(" ) "\\)"} (3.8.001)]
```

Backslash has to be used twice, to have a single backslash when used inside double quotes in Tcl.

Comment: i have a question. how to replace . into new line?

Comment: @ArunBaskar : `string map {"." "\n"} (3.8.001)`